# How to convert ctypes.c_uint32 to int in python?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am getting some value inside a struct, whose member is of type `ctypes.c_uint32`, when I try to print this value, it rather prints the characteristics of that variable like type, offset, size. I need to use that value in python program so how to convert it to int.?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Those objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) have the [`value` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._SimpleCData.value):

```
In [14]: ct = ctypes.c_uint32(42)

In [15]: type(ct)
Out[15]: ctypes.c_uint

In [16]: ct.value
Out[16]: 42

In [17]: type(ct.value) is int
Out[17]: True
```

Comment: Probably unimportant, but in Python 2.7 `ctypes.c_uint32(42).value` is 42L (a long) and `type(ctypes.c_uint32(42).value)` emits `<type 'long'>`.

Comment: the value i am getting is of type `_ctypes.CFeild`, and when i try `variable.value` it gives error that `_ctypes.CField has no attribute value`, I am sure that value is `ctypes.c_uint32`.. so wanting to convert that into int